# Default font sizes in X11 apps under MobaXterm V12

Tags: fonts, x11, mobaxterm

I use the free tier of [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) on Windows to connect to our Centos/RHEL machines and to display X11 apps on the Windows desktop.

In the past I used **MobaXterm V3** and it displayed X11 apps like PyCharm, Eclipse or VS code with appropriate font sizes. Here an sample portion of the PyCharm window under MobaXterm V3:

[image: Fonts in Version 3]

Now I upgraded to the current **MobaXterm V12** and the fonts for menus and explorer panes are way too big:

[image: Fonts in version 12]

This happens not only in PyCharm, but in other X11 apps like Eclipse as well - and in apps on different remote machines. So it must have to do with the X server built into MobaXterm.

I compared the output of `xset q` under both X servers and got the following differences (in the graphics section of the `xset` output):

**MobaXterm V3**
:   `Font Path: /usr/share/fonts/misc,built-ins`

**MobaXterm V12**
:   `Font Path: C:\Users\broleo\AppData\Local\Temp\Mxt121/usr/share/fonts/misc/,built-ins`

I tried to set the font path in V12 via `xset fp` to the same as in V3, but it didn't help.

Any idea what to do to make the new MobaXterm V3 display X11 apps with fonts in a similar size as in the old MobaXterm V3?

---

*Note:* I know that most apps offer in-app preferences to change font sizes; but often this applies only to editor text, etc and it would need to be done for each app separately. I am rather looking for a tweak to MobaXterm V12 - after all V3 can do it!

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming-related question, but anyway, check the dpi settings of your X11 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Changelog](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download-home-edition.html) for version 12.0

> Improvement: added a new X11 DPI setting in order to force X server
>   DPI value (useful for HighDPI monitors)

Go to:

1. Settings
2. Configuration
3. X11

And change value in DPI drop-down until you get the correct display.

Comment: It's a simple answer, but it got me sorted. :-)